# MySQL: Insert into a table from another HOST

Tags: mysql

So I would like to copy some records from one table to another. But the trick is that the another table is in a different HOST. I will try to explain by giving you a mysql query pseudo code.

```
Another_host = "192.168.X.X";

INSERT INTO database_original.table_1( id, name, surname)
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM Another_host.database_another.table_2
WHERE Another_host.database_another.table_2.id > 1000;
```

I would probably have to declare the user for the "Another_host" somewhere.
This is what I am trying to do..is this even possible like I imagine it?

Thx

Comment: My typical solution for this situation is to use a scripting language, like PHP. Would that be an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround solution which will do the same what you want.

**Step 1:**
Take dump of select query

```
mysql -e "select * from myTable" -h <<firsthost>> -u myuser -pxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.sql
```

**Step 2:** Restore the dump

```
mysql -h <<secondhost>> -u myuser -pxxxxxxxx < mydumpfile.sql
```

Comment: I was thinking of this workaround, but the table is 1Gb big. So for the first time I would export it and import in another HOST DB..but then I want just to update it..the user will have the power to update the table with one button click..I cannot make the user wait for 1Gb of export/import every time :/